# How to precompute foldid with even observations per fold for glmnet

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet

According to the [glmnet vignette](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html), a `foldid` can be set up by:

```
foldid=sample(1:10,size=length(y),replace=TRUE)
```

However, if you look at the number of observations in each of the folds:

```
> table(foldid)
foldid
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
10 12  8  7 12 12  8  7 14 10
```

The distribution is not very even. I am getting huge variation in the `cvm`/`lambda.min` each time I run `cv.glmnet` with `foldid` precomputed by the method above (on my own datasets; n<30), and want to try a `foldid` with more even distribution of observations. Could somebody suggest a way (code) to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind. Found an answer in the [glmnet manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf).

```
(n = 100)
> foldid=sample(rep(seq(10),length=n))
> table(foldid)
foldid
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

All the folds have the same number of observations.

Comment: FWIW, cvTools provides some functions to create folds as well.

Comment: Accept your own answer after the 2 day period if it was the correct answer to your question.